# Application is not recognized by Game Center

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center

Whenever I authenticate my IOS user in my Xcode simulator (iPhone X), I get the following error:

```
Optional(Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=15 "The requested operation could not be completed because this application is not recognized by Game Center." UserInfo={GKServerStatusCode=5019, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation could not be completed because this application is not recognized by Game Center., NSUnderlyingError=0x60000330f180 {Error Domain=GKServerErrorDomain Code=5019 "status = 5019, no game matching descriptor: ios:com.myteam.platform:1.0:1+-1" UserInfo={GKServerStatusCode=5019, NSLocalizedFailureReason=status = 5019, no game matching descriptor: ios: com.myteam.platform:1.0:1+-1}}})
```

I followed the steps found [here](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev60b6fbbc7). Briefly, I have an IOS certificate linked to a developer team, and used the Xcode project settings to create a `Bundle Identifier` with a distinct name, `Automatically manage signing` with my team name, and Game Center turned on under the `Capabilities` tab. What am I missing to connect this app to the Game Center for development? All of the old SO questions were answered by turning on Game Center Sandbox, but that is not an option in IOS anymore.